# Shared memory is executing so fast?

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, shared-memory

what i am trying to do in kernel :

```
while (TRUE)
{
    //DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "First loop is running \n");
    ReadSharedMemory();


        if (!(PCHAR)SharedSection == NULL && strcmp((PCHAR)SharedSection, "Read") == 0)
        {
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Read looping \n");

            RtlZeroMemory(SharedSection, sizeof(SharedSection));
            break;
        }
        else if (!(PCHAR)SharedSection == NULL && strcmp((PCHAR)SharedSection, "Write") == 0)
        {
            DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Write looping \n");
            RtlZeroMemory(SharedSection, sizeof(SharedSection));
            break;
        }
    LARGE_INTEGER Timeout;
    Timeout.QuadPart = RELATIVE(SECONDS(1));
    KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, &Timeout);
}
```

and in user mode :

```
    auto pBufW = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFileW, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);


RtlCopyMemory(pBufW, "Read", 4);

printf("message has been sent to kernel! \n");


UnmapViewOfFile(pBufW);

Sleep(10);

auto pBfW = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFileW, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 4096);


RtlCopyMemory(pBfW, "Write", 5);

printf("message has been sent to kernel! \n");


UnmapViewOfFile(pBfW);
```

i can't figure it out why when i call Read and Write . only Write execute i have tried it multiple times and its always doing this + i have tried to add a sleep(1); in my user mode (thought it was executing real fast).

basically i just need them to execute normally like Read should be executed first then Write .

Comment: If you mean `if (SharedSection != nullptr)` then please write it that way...

Comment: Also, `strcmp` requires a **NUL-terminated** string, which you aren't providing...

Comment: @Ben Voigt
`RtlCopyMemory(pBfW, "Write", 5);` i am , see "Write" is 6 chars including the null terminator i do 5 ? could you explain how could i do that if am doing it with the wrong way .

Comment: for what you use `MapViewOfFile` at all ? what sense in this ?

Comment: @RbMm for sending strings to my driver to communicate with it ?

Comment: but what sense in this ? for what you need section ??

Comment: @RbMm  to share that string with my kernel driver , it loops until it see's it then it execute

Comment: for what you need section ???

Comment: @RbMm to share that string with my kernel driver , it loops until it see's it then it execute i already said that ?

Comment: for what you need section for share ??

Comment: @RbMm to share it with my kernel driver ?

Comment: again, for what you need section ?? kernel driver have direct access for user memory

Comment: @RbMm  i didn't not mention that , i want to use sections to send string to my kernel driver that has a while loop in it and if a string is met then it will execute. and i don't want to use any systemthreads , deviceioControl so that's why am using shared sections

Comment: again, you not need any section. this is absolute senseless here. how *systemthreads* here related at all ?

Comment: @RbMm then how are you going to do it then with WriteFile and ReadFile . ? i don't want to do it that way that's why am using sections

Comment: @Frankoo - ok, no sense explain more

Comment: @RbMm ok its like that my driver has a while loop that is running in the background all the time , when i pass a string via a mapped section from my user mode app it compare that string and if its equal then it execute what is in the if statement and then it keeps looping and reading from the sharedsection .

Answer (score 0):

someone helped me with it , this is what i did

```
  while ( memcmp( pBufW, "Read", 4) == 0 )
    {
           Sleep(1);
    }
UnmapViewOfFile(pBufW);
```

simple check and it works fine now :D